# session handling for request object in wicket framework

Tags: java, frameworks, wicket

1) i have added an element in request object given below, i need to get/read this in my webpage, how can i do it?

```
<input type="hidden"> wicket:id="submitted" value="false" />
```

eg: in servlet, use request.getParameter("submitted") from hidden session.

2) in my controller class i want to set the value in session or hidden field, so that i can identify the user if he already processed the request or enetered my block of code.

Answer (score 1):

1) use [`HiddenField`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/index.html?org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/HiddenField.html)

2) use a custom [`WebSession`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/WebSession.html) object:

```
public class MySession extends WebSession{
    public Mysession(Request request){super(request);}
    private boolean completedRegistration;

    public boolean hasCompletedRegistration() {
        return completedRegistration;
    }

    public void setCompletedRegistration(boolean completedRegistration) {
        this.completedRegistration = completedRegistration;
    }
}
```

Comment: my main class already extending panel ie public class LoginSafePanel extends Panel { and static class extends another classs as shown above. this is existing class, need to bug fix ;)

Comment: @akb no Problem, use `add(new HiddenField("submitted", "false"))`

Comment: im new to wicket, how cam i get/read this value? can u update in ur answer?

Comment: @akb StackOverflow is no substitute for learning the Languages / Frameworks you use. Get a Wicket Book or read the [reference manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/reference-library.html)

Comment: thanks, there is no construcor for HiddenField(String, String)

Comment: @akb true, sorry. Then use `add(new HiddenField("submitted", Model.of("false")))`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have fully understood your questions.

But to make it short, if you want to get the value stored in your request object, you'll need to make the model of your input map to this value (by using `HiddenField` wicket internal class).

If you want to track your user, the best thing to do is looking around for a cookie set on the client side that'll allow you to manage its visits.

Please refine your question if you want a more precise answer...