# wicket onrendered values

Tags: java, frameworks, wicket

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [session handling for request object in wicket framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174472/session-handling-for-request-object-in-wicket-framework)

1) i have added an element in request object(html page given below, i need to get/read this in my webpage, how can i do it?

```
<input type="hidden"> wicket:id="submitted" value="false" />
```

eg: in servlet, use request.getParameter("submitted") from hidden session.

2) in my controller class i want to set the value in session or hidden field, so that i can identify the user if he already processed the request or enetered my block of code.

I have code like this: my aim is, once this code is executed, i need to put condition "if" and not to proceed further if he is already executed this.

```
    static private class SafeSubmitBehaviour extends AbstractBehavior{

        public void onRendered( Component component ) {
            super.onRendered( component );    
if(what condition i need to put here?){
//    if false dont go inside
}
```

Since on rendered method is executing many times in perticular situation. so i want to put some condition to stop further.